# How to Drawing a curve line(peaks) using list of x,y coordinates

Tags: java, graphics2d, curve, bezier

I have a list of x,y points which printed,display an uneven peak curve line.

[image]

The above image was generated by just painting the points on a java paint component. I used the following way to paint them on a paint component.

```
g.drawline(pointX,pointY,pointX,pointY)
```

Are there better ways to paint such wave line? I checked some of the similar questions,often they need to print a curve or peak,but my line is not always  a peak as some times its flats out and other times they are bizarre.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864441/how-to-make-a-line-curve-through-points)? Or something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/primitives.html)?

Comment: It was helpful,but when using lines and points to draw curve lines,they tend to pixalate when we zoom in using 'g.scale' function. Are there ways to smooth the curves or should i be looking for some curve lib for these kind of things?

Comment: Take a look at [`RenderingHints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/quality.html), but, remember, scaling up is hard then scaling and down and instead of scaling the pixels, I'd scale the points and simply repaint them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to draw polylines with `java.awt.Graphics` is to use the `drawPolyline` method. It requires you to have your x and y coordinates stored in separate `int[]` arrays, but it is much faster and clearer than to draw each line segment individually.

If you need floating-point coordinates, the best way would be to use a [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) object with `Graphics2D`. Unfortunately, Java does not seem to provide a polyline `Shape` implementation, but you can easily use [`Path2D`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html):

```
Graphics2D graphics = /* your graphics object */;
double[] x = /* x coordinates of polyline */;
double[] y = /* y coordinates of polyline */;

Path2D polyline = new Path2D.Double();
polyline.moveTo(x[0], y[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
    polyline.lineTo(x[i], y[i]);
}

graphics.draw(polyline);
```

This way allows you to easily transform you coordinates, too -- however, it may be more efficient to transform the view, of course.