# java plotting spline curves with double data

Tags: java, user-interface, graph

I know  basic coding in Java and a little about GUI in java.I have some programs written myself that can generate data in the form of arrays of data type double. I wana create a java program that consists of classes  which can take these arrays as input and  plot graph with spline curve for the given data.I cannot do it on my own .Can anyone please give me such code.

Comment: Try to see this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15864441/how-to-make-a-line-curve-through-points

Comment: Actually my intention is to draw a smooth curve using those points.I thought it will be a spline.Am I right to ask the question as drawing a spline curve?